# How do I add a header to a VB.NET 2008 SOAP request?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, soap, siebel

I have a VB.NET 2008 program that accesses a Siebel web service defined by a WSDL and using the SOAP protocol.

The Siebel web service requires that a header containing the username, password and session type be included with the service request, but the header is not defined in the WSDL.

So, when I test the WSDL using the soapUI utility, the request as defined by the WSDL looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lov="http://www.siebel.com/xml/LOVService" xmlns:lis="http://www.siebel.com/xml/ListQuery">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <lov:EAILOVGetListOfValues_Input>
         <lis:ListsQuery>
            <lis:ListQuery>
               <lis:Active>Y</lis:Active>
               <lis:LanguageCode>ENU</lis:LanguageCode>
               <lis:Type>CUT_ACCOUNT_TYPE</lis:Type>
            </lis:ListQuery>
         </lis:ListsQuery>
      </lov:EAILOVGetListOfValues_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the above does not work because it contains an empty header that is missing user and session credentials. It only works if I manually replace `<soapenv:Header/>` with a header containing the username, password, and session type as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lov="http://www.siebel.com/xml/LOVService" xmlns:lis="http://www.siebel.com/xml/ListQuery">
<soapenv:Header>
  <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">TESTUSER</UsernameToken>
  <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">TESTPASSWORD</PasswordText>
  <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <lov:EAILOVGetListOfValues_Input>
         <lis:ListsQuery>
            <lis:ListQuery>
               <lis:Active>Y</lis:Active>
               <lis:LanguageCode>ENU</lis:LanguageCode>
               <lis:Type>CUT_ACCOUNT_TYPE</lis:Type>
            </lis:ListQuery>
         </lis:ListsQuery>
      </lov:EAILOVGetListOfValues_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My problem is that I cannot sort out how to translate the above into VB.NET 2008 code.

I have no problem importing the WSDL into Visual Studio 2008, defining the service in VB code and referencing the web service methods. However, I cannot sort out how to define the web service in VB such that the updated header in included in the web service request instead of the empty header. Consequently all my service requests from VB fail.

I can define a class that inherits from the SoapHeader class...

```
Public Class MySoapHeader : Inherits System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public SessionType As String
End Class
```

...but how do I include this header in the SOAP request made from VB?

The sample code I am using to test this is a simple form with a button and a list box.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnGetLOV_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetLOV.Click

        Dim MyService As New wsLOV.EAILOVPortClient

        Dim MyInput As New wsLOV.EAILOVGetListOfValues_Input
        Dim MyParams(0) As wsLOV.ListQuery
        Dim temp As New wsLOV.ListQuery

        Dim MyResult As New wsLOV.EAILOVGetListOfValues_Output

        temp.Active = "Y"
        temp.Type = "CUT_ACCOUNT_TYPE"
        temp.LanguageCode = "ENU"
        MyParams(0) = temp

        MyInput.ListsQuery = MyParams

        Dim MyRequest As New wsLOV.EAILOVGetListOfValuesRequest(MyInput)
        MyResult = MyService.EAILOVGetListOfValues(MyInput)


    End Sub

End Class
```

The code fails on the last line of the subroutine with a message indicating that the request has not been authenticated (Error Code: 10944642 Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP Message - Session Token is missing or invalid or has expired) which is the same error I get in soapUI when I leave off the header containing username, password, and session type.

I believe I need to add the header to the endpoint (per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731749.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.serviceendpointelement.aspx) but I am not sure how to do this in VB.

Comment: the WSDL for the service is broken, the service provider needs to fix the WSDL.

Comment: It's not broke. The WSDL was auto-generated by Siebel.

Comment: that does not mean it isn't or can't be broke.

Comment: Key question is what is your client proxy is it a new service client or an old-school web reference?

Comment: Just edited the post to include additional information on the test client I am using. The wsLOV name is a service reference defined by the WSDL file (using VS2008's "Add Service Reference" dialog.

Comment: Can we see the end point stuff from the web.config?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how we resolved this issue. The key seems to be instantiating the endpoint with the additional header, and not trying to add the header after the endpoint is already instantiated.

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels
Imports System.ServiceModel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnGetOrg_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetOrgType.Click
        ' This example code queries the Siebel web service using the SOAP protocol for a list of
        ' Account (organization) types stored in a List of Values (LOV). The service request
        ' requires that a SOAP header be added that contains the username, password, and session
        ' type. We have to add this header because the WSDL file definition generated by Siebel
        ' does not include the header definition. The WSDL file was added to the VS2008 project as
        ' a Service Reference named "wsGetLOV"

        ' Create address headers for special services and add them to an array
        Dim addressHeader1 As AddressHeader = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("UsernameToken", "http://siebel.com/webservices", "TESTUSER")
        Dim addressHeader2 As AddressHeader = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("PasswordText", "http://siebel.com/webservices", "TESTPASSWORD")
        Dim addressHeader3 As AddressHeader = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("SessionType", "http://siebel.com/webservices", "None")
        Dim addressHeaders() As AddressHeader = {addressHeader1, addressHeader2, addressHeader3}

        ' Endpoint address constructor with URI and address headers
        ' Replace <servername> in the following line with the name of your Siebel server.
        ' For example: http://actual-server/eai_enu...
        Dim endpointAddressWithHeaders As New EndpointAddress(New Uri("http://<servername>/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&WSSOAP=1"), addressHeaders)
        Dim MyService As New wsGetLOV.EAILOVPortClient("EAILOVPort", endpointAddressWithHeaders)

        Dim MyInput As New wsGetLOV.EAILOVGetListOfValues_Input
        Dim MyOutput As wsGetLOV.EAILOVGetListOfValues_Output
        Dim MyList(0) As wsGetLOV.ListQuery

        MyList(0) = New wsGetLOV.ListQuery
        MyList(0).Active = "Y"
        MyList(0).LanguageCode = "ENU"
        MyList(0).Type = "CUT_ACCOUNT_TYPE"
        MyInput.ListsQuery = MyList

        MyOutput = MyService.EAILOVGetListOfValues(MyInput)

        Dim myStrings As New List(Of String)

        ' We use nested loops because the results returned by the service is a list of
        ' lists though in our case, the result set is a list with a single item (this item
        ' being a list of multiple items)
        For Each myResultList As wsGetLOV.ListResult In MyOutput.ListsResult
            For Each myResultValue As wsGetLOV.ListValueResult In myResultList.ListValuesResult
                myStrings.Add(myResultValue.Value)
            Next
        Next

        ListBox1.DataSource = myStrings

    End Sub
End Class
```